# Android - ImageView изменение размера, резкие границы.

Tags: android, изображения

Доброго времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой изменения размера изображения. Как видно на [скриншоте](http://ipic.su/img/img7/fs/Screenshot_2014-04-13-12-25-51.1397370309.png), изображение имеет резкие границы. Само изображения 2000x400px (2000 пикселей в ширину и 400 в высоту). Есть ли какой-то способ (помимо создания такого же изображения под все размеры экранов) уменьшать изображение без эффекта резкости? Если нету, то каких тогда размеров должны быть изображения?
p.s. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Уменьшите хотя бы до 1000х200, уже будет лучше. А вообще, такие большие изображения в приложении - непорядок. Погуглите про размеры экранов и их плотность.

Comment: а зачем это делать картинкой? стили вам на что?

Comment: В стилях есть тень текста? А шрифт Klavika Bold? А шрифт Agletterica Condensed?

Comment: что такое эффект резкости ? для мастабирования используйте класс Matrix. например canvas.drawBitmap использует матрицу.

Comment: а разве "обглоданные края" не видно? Особенно на букве S что справа?)) пару-тройку пикселей будто бы просто срезали) Такой эффект наблюдается при увеличении резкости изображения.
Насчет остального - не найду ни одного адекватного примера.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сделаю ответ полноценный из идеи в комментариях: 
С визуализацией текста в android можно делать много чего, [вот пример тому](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/customize-android-fonts--mobile-1601). Там вы найдете и как тень сделать у текста, и как можно задать кастомный шрифт, и может еще что-то